# How to get device colors?

Tags: android, look-and-feel, branding, android-theme

I have a spinner which is in the Emulator light gray with black text also on HTC devices. On the Motorola Defy the control is dark-gray and the text is white.

How can I get the default text color of the currient device?

Comment: which device r u using..

Comment: HTC Desire HD and Motorola Defy

Comment: on  thing i can say ,i have also faced same problem to motorola droid devices for which the device color is white.. we need to set the text color..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Macarse goes in the right direction but I uses another way.

I looked in the `/platforms/android-X/data/res/values` xml files and got the color `background_dark` which works for me.

Finnally I uses this code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem> {
    // ...

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tv.setTextColor(Resources.getSystem().getColor(android.R.color.background_dark));
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the customizations done by carries/manufactures are inside:

- `android:colors`
- `android:styles`
- `android:themes`

If you are using a `TextView` you can check the default text color by creating a `TextView` object and calling [getTextColors()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTextColors%28%29).

Another possibility is checking how the styles are applied to the `TextView` and using the `getResource()` method to get the exact color you are looking for.

Comment: I cannot figger out the right variable in android.R.color for the text color of a spinner

Comment: @rekire: You will need to take a look at `Spinner` styles. You can read them in the SDK folder inside `/platforms/android-X/data/res/values/styles.xml`