# How to get Android system Colors?

Tags: android, colors, background, system

I'm searching way to get Android system colors - color theme used in device.

Using `android:color/` I didn't get correct colors.
For example: background color in my device is `BLACK`, menu background color is `DARKGREY`.
Values from `android:color/` in device is: only `BLACK` and `WHITE` backgrounds.

Comment: See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166851/how-to-get-device-colors

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for rekire :)

Finally I have the answer:
[Android: How to get background color of Activity in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656586/android-how-to-get-background-color-of-activity-in-java)

```
TypedArray array = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{android.R.attr.colorBackground,}); 
int backgroundcolor = array.getColor(0, 0xFF00FF);
```

Comment: You have to free the array afterwards!
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598414/get-an-edittexts-default-color-value-from-theme

Answer (score 16):

You can get android system color using

```
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
```

And this is working fine

Comment: None of these gives me DARKGRAY /backcolor of my menu/  android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
  android:background="@android:color/background_light"

Comment: Instead of background_dark and background_light you can use your custom color by giving alpha,red,green and blue color code.

Comment: Yep. But first I have to know colors used in device. Because I want to make my icons with system used colors.

Comment: There is a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192798/how-to-get-android-system-colors

Comment: `resource android:color/yellow not found` system doesn't have yellow? even more interesting: `error: resource android:color/red is private.`

Answer (score 0):

It might just be setting a color filter on whatever the base color of the device is. That may be why you're not getting the base color you were expecting.

This is just a theory, I haven't verified it yet. Either that, or the base color for the theme  you're looking is stored in a slightly different location. That's also a possibility.

Comment: I'm trying to use system colors for background in my dialogs, views, toolbars. My idea is to use plain icons with color filter.

Comment: Have you tried making your WHITE color darker with a color filter until it replicates your DARKGREY? Chances are, your plain icons will also be black and white, so you should be able to replicate the black and darkgrey perfectly I think.

Comment: Do you know way to get color filter used in this case?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I'd only be guessing and trying different color filters until I got to the right one. Hopefully, someone else has a quicker way to get to that same information.