# Why should a TypedArray be recycled?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, typedarray

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252839/what-is-the-use-of-recycle-method-in-typedarray) tells me that calling the [`recycle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#recycle()) method of a TypedArray allows for it to be garbage collected. My question is why TypedArray specifically needs a method for it to be garbage collected? Why can't it just wait to be garbage collected like a regular object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is required for caching purporse. When you call `recycle` it means that this object can be reused from this point. Internally `TypedArray` contains few arrays so in order not to allocate memory each time when `TypedArray` is used it is cached in `Resources` class as static field. You can look at `TypedArray.recycle()` method code:

```
/**
 * Give back a previously retrieved StyledAttributes, for later re-use.
 */
public void recycle() {
    synchronized (mResources.mTmpValue) {
        TypedArray cached = mResources.mCachedStyledAttributes;
        if (cached == null || cached.mData.length < mData.length) {
            mXml = null;
            mResources.mCachedStyledAttributes = this;
        }
    }
}
```

So when you call `recycle` your `TypedArray` object is just returned back to cache.

Comment: /**
     * Recycle the TypedArray, to be re-used by a later caller. After calling
     * this function you must not ever touch the typed array again.
     */
    public void recycle() {
        if (mRecycled) {
            throw new RuntimeException(toString() + " recycled twice!");
        }

        mRecycled = true;

        // These may have been set by the client.
        mXml = null;
        mTheme = null;

        mResources.mTypedArrayPool.release(this);
    }

Answer (score 4):

@Andrei Mankevich
I just check the newest version of Android SDK, and it seems there are some changes make to recycle(). Please check the below codes:

```
/**
 * Recycle the TypedArray, to be re-used by a later caller. After calling
 * this function you must not ever touch the typed array again.
 */
public void recycle() {
    if (mRecycled) {
        throw new RuntimeException(toString() + " recycled twice!");
    }

    mRecycled = true;

    // These may have been set by the client.
    mXml = null;
    mTheme = null;

    mResources.mTypedArrayPool.release(this);
}
```